# Seeking Web Feature Service (WFS) software

Tags: open-source, json, gis

My goal is to set up a Web Feature Service (WFS) to implement real time data in a local GIS.

The data is stored in a `MySQL` db, it is fetched by `PHP` and returned as `JSON` with lat and lon. This `JSON` data needs to be displayed in a local GIS and should update itself (e.g. daily) if something is changed in the db.

So far my main problem e.g. with GeoServer was, that I was unable to link the `PHP result` as data directly.

Or is it even possible to implement the `JSON data` straight in e.g. QGIS/ArcGIS? But so far I found no way to do so...

Comment: GeoServer would replace your Php code by directly connecting to MySQL and returning GeoJSON (or GML, etc)

Comment: the structure of the data in the db is not suitable for a direct connection, therefore PHP to prepare the data

Comment: Then you need to write a custom datastore, or an sql view to modify the data.

Comment: I tried a sql view but it took like forever... Do you have some experience with custom datastores and can give me a hint where to start with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6186142/439194